# How to get symbol info from libmlx5-rdmav2.so?

Tags: linux, debugging, intel, intel-vtune, rdma

I am using Vtune to analyze my program. And the Vtune reports that

```
Function                      Module              CPU Time  % of CPU Time(%)
----------------------------  -----------------  ---------  ----------------
func@0x23dc0                  libmlx5-rdmav2.so  1779.256s             50.4%
__memmove_avx_unaligned_erms  libc.so.6           798.907s             22.6%
pollOnce                      io500               300.626s              8.5%
RpcClient::do_get             io500               284.459s              8.1%
ibv_poll_cq                   io500               179.388s              5.1%
```

I hope to know what's inside the `func@0x23dc0  libmlx5-rdmav2.so`.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get the symbols would be to compile your own version of the `libibverbs` library and its provider drivers. The source code for the upstream version is available at https://github.com/linux-rdma/rdma-core.

In addition, some Linux distributions (e.g., [Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages), [RedHat](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/debuginfo-install.1.html)) hold repositories for debugging symbols of their libraries.

Finally, note that in many polling applications, a profiler might not tell you what you want to know, as they constantly call polling functions, whether or not they produce output.